# My JS function for my wordgame keeps throwing script error in Firefox ONLY

Tags: javascript, firefox

Well, there was me thinking my JS wordgame  was functioning beautifully ( with a little help from Ryan J - thanks!). I was about to begin adding styling when I realised that I hadn't tested in Firefox at all - my bad, I got the dreaded script timeout error. So, after hours of testing and playing around I still can't understand what's wrong. I'm being told by the error that it's the following function that's causing the problem:

```
function guessLetter( letter, shown, answer ) {
    var checkIndex = 0; 
    checkIndex = answer.indexOf(letter);
    while (checkIndex >= 0) {
        shown = alterAt(checkIndex, letter, shown);
        checkIndex = answer.indexOf(letter, checkIndex + 1);
    }
    return shown;
}
```

alterAt is previously defined, totally puzzled - any tips most welcomed.

Thanks

Terry

EDT: Oops! Here's a link - completely unstyled but you get the idea.

http://theelectricunderground.net/eltel/currentaffairs/wordpress/?p=449

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does `checkIndex` get to be less than 0? Where in your code is the script timeout error being thrown in Firefox?

Comment: @krillgar: `String.prototype.indexOf`: "Returns -1 if the value is not found."

Comment: Hi Krillgar - thanks for getting back - it's throwing the error on exactly that line, I robbed this function from another program so I'll look into it - seems you are onto something :/

Comment: Is it possible that `letter` is an empty string? This would explain the infinite loop.

Comment: Also, this is an infinite loop in chrome as well, it just doesn't display a dialogue

Comment: @krillgar when `letter` is not in `answer` then it is -1

Comment: @soktinpkI was just playing with the code it should be fine now - it works fine in both ie and Chrome. ...I'm baffled

Comment: I think you need to press the same letter twice... try it?

Comment: The code has been restored to my original code as I just accidentally broke it  - sorry guys, it should be fine now.

Comment: @TerryMitchell Then just try typing really fast. It definitely creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed it... this is because `letter` is an empty string. You should add something like this to your code (in the keypress event):

```
if (tempChar === "") return;
```

before the line

```
tempString = guessLetter(tempChar, gameShownAnswer, gameAnswer );
```

This is because sometimes the `keyup` event occurs but there is nothing in the input box.
For example, what happens when you press the control key?

The index of an empty string never be `-1`, so the loop will never break.

For example, `"petrol".indexOf("", 100)` returns `6`.

Comment: By Jove he's done it!! I'm eternally indebted to you :) I've accepted your answer and as soon as I reach fifteen (still a real noob on here - obvious right! lol) I'll mark your answer up. Many thanks!

Comment: Explanation really helped too BTW, nicely put. :)